# Should I use a d4 for unarmed strikes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, unarmed-combat

In the PH, it says that unarmed strikes deal "1 + your strength modifier". However, that still seems kinda weak to me - what do you use in terms of unarmed strikes? At least one of my players swears that it's a d4+STR, and again, I feel that 1 lousy damage for a full-on punch/headbutt/whatever is a little low. On the other hand, if it was 1d4 and it was combined with the flurry of blows, that could be kinda broken. What do you think, o wise answer people?

Comment: This question isn't unclear, it's just polling for opinions.  I'm VTCing, and it'll end up closed as unclear, but that's the real problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because opinion polls and forum-like discussion questions are not appropriate for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10):

The rules are clear on this:

> On a hit, an unarmed strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your
>   Strength modifier. (PHB 195, Errata v1.0)

And it makes sense: would a punch hurt as much as a stab with a dagger, which uses a d4?

Note that a character might deal more damage with his unarmed strikes, e.g. by taking the Tavern Brawler feat (d4) or being a monk (d4 or better, depending on level).

Answer (score 4):

As a DM you can rule however you want. I've seen rulings as 1d2 or 1d3 even. But it does nullify some aspects.

- Large part of monk's starting class features
- Racial features like Tabaxi
- Improvised weapons for stand-in or quick weapons.
- Many simple weapons become useless if you can punch for the same (club and light hammer for instance).
- Tavern brawler feat.

Instead I would suggest the player take the Tavern Brawler feat if they wish for their punches to do more damage. Representing them learning how to punch more effectively.